# Why does animation affect idleHandler?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-looper

idleHandler will not be executed after this code run：

```
if (operatingAnim == null) {
    operatingAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(BocaiApplication.getInstance(), R.anim.rotate);
    operatingAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
}
iv.clearAnimation();
iv.startAnimation(operatingAnim);
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with the same issue. Repeated animations block calling `IdleHandler` of the corresponding `MessageQueue` instances and therefore `ActivityScenario.onActivity()` never executes the passed code block. Did you find any solution? I also found this issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36981049, but it does not help.